# Made a custom form module how do i submit data usging magento functions only?

Tags: database, module, register

I made a custom form module which has its own DB table that was supposed to get data from the form submission

this is my Form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('merchant/index/save')?>" id="merchant-reg" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="lableninput">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="required-entry" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div class="lableninput">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="required-entry validate-email"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div class="lableninput">
            <label for="store_name">Store Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="store_name" class="required-entry"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <input type="submit" value ="Procced to Checkout"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('merchant-reg', true)
    //]]>
</script>
</html>
```

and this my controller

```
 public function saveAction()
 {
     $this->getRequest()->getPost();

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($this);
     echo "<pre>";

     $fromdata = Mage::getSingleton('frontend/session')->getData('merchant-reg');

     print_r($fromdata);

     $data = Mage::getSingleton("frontend/session")->getFormData(true);

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($data);
 }
```

I have tried all three ways to get form data but no luck what am I doing wrong?

this is my model code

```
class Eshop_Merchant_Model_Merchnat extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct(){

       $this->_init("merchant/merchant");

    }

}
```

Comment: Try with `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()`. You have the line in there. You just don't use it.

Comment: @Marius  How do i add this data to DB table . is there function if column name and field id/class is the same  ? or i have to do the core php way ?

Comment: I assume you have a model for your entity. If so, you need this:  `Mage::getModel('[module]/[entity]')->setData($data)->save()`

Comment: @Marius i added my model code above will it do the trick ?

Comment: seams right. Try with `Mage::getModel('merchant/merchant')->setData($data)->save()`

Comment: @Marius it gave a fatal error saying "
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object"

Comment: This means that your model is not declared in the config.xml . This should clear the fog: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: @Marius config.xml already contains this code <models>
   <merchant>
  <class>Eshop_Merchant_Model</class>
  <resourceModel>merchant_mysql4</resourceModel>
   </merchant>
   <merchant_mysql4>
  <class>Eshop_Merchant_Model_Mysql4</class>
  <entities>    
     <merchnat>
    <table>merchant</table>
     </merchnat>
        </entities>
   </merchant_mysql4>
 </models>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public function saveAction
{
   $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($post);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: How do i add this data to DB table . is there function if column name and field id/class is the same  ? or i have to do the core php way ?